# Drupal Core Bartik Theme - Pager Problem

Tags: theming, paging

URL: /admin/store/products/attributes/

Uber:7.x-3.8      Drupal:7.37

i haven't this problem with older Drupal versions
When I check my att list page in Ubercart with Bartik core theme I see:

```
<div class="content">
<table class="sticky-header" ....</table>
<table class="sticky-enabled tableheader-processed sticky-table">
....
</table>
```

but in Garland theme i have pager

```
<div class="content">
<table class="sticky-header" ....</table>
<table class="sticky-enabled tableheader-processed sticky-table">
....
</table>

<h2 class="element-invisible">Pages</h2>
<div class="item-list"><ul class="pager"><li class="pager-current first">1</li>
    <li class="pager-item"><a href="/en/admin/store/products/attributes?page=1&amp;sort=asc&amp;order=%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85" title="Go to page 2">2</a></li>
    <li class="pager-item"><a href="/en/admin/store/products/attributes?page=2&amp;sort=asc&amp;order=%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85" title="Go to page 3">3</a></li>
    <li class="pager-next"><a href="/en/admin/store/products/attributes?page=1&amp;sort=asc&amp;order=%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85" title="Go to next page">next ›</a></li>
    <li class="pager-last last"><a href="/en/admin/store/products/attributes?page=2&amp;sort=asc&amp;order=%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85" title="Go to last page">last »</a></li>
</ul></div>
  </div>
```

I tried replacing template.tpl.php or node.tpl.php or page.tpl.php markup. And tried  tracing for item-list without finding the cause of the issue. Any idea how to get the pager in the Bartik theme?

Comment: Is this att list page a catalog display? To troubleshoot the problem, you need to describe how/where the table is located in your site.